# xkb: Correct way to interact with it on Mint 15/Ubuntu 13

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mapping, linux-mint

I would like to know what is the currently approved way to interact with the X11 xkb apparatus to effect changes in the keyboard layout. (For Mint 15 Cinnamon, though I suspect Ubuntu 13 would be a close match for this topic).

I studied up on xkb, especially using An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration (http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/).

OK, so I think I know how to specify what I want in xkb concepts, using keycodes, keysyms, compat and so forth. However, relative to "Unreliable":

1. The xkb-related files are in different directory locations. OK, but...
2. I can't figure out what top-level config file actually invokes the particular xkb components ("Unreliable" discusses XF86Config-4, which is obsolete.) There are many different files in each subdirectory of /usr/share/X11/xkb, but I don't see how particular ones are selected.
3. I am assuming there's supposed to be a way to add user-specific overrides via user-specific xkb config files in ~/, but I've found no evidence how to do.

I did notice that there's a /etc/default/keyboard file, which sets some variables like XKBMODEL and XKBLAYOUT etc that look promising, but I have no idea what substitutions and syntax can be used there, nor if and when that takes effect.

Looking forward to enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem here.

I used to be able to change the files in earlier ubuntu Versions in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/

I just made a copy of the de file and changed what I wanted to in there. Used to be pretty easy, as the systems just overrides the included "latin4"-Layout.

Guides are also found here: http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/~mikosmul/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html

It seems as though Mint 15 is not using these files anymore?

Update: found this: http://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/linux+--+keyboard+configuration,+xkb

Update 2: After changes to the file in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ you have to manually delete the files in /var/lib/xkb to empty the system-cache for keymapings